# Smart table: conditional st-sort attribute in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using Angular Smart Table and it is pretty good, but i faced with problem related to sorting:

let's assume that i have some columns definition and for each column i have information whether i can sort by this column or not:

```
$scope.columns = [
    {
        id: "id",
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        id: "type",
        sortable: false,
    }
];
```

In my html file i want to declare table headers with ng-repeat to avoid stupid refactoring when something in columns definition is changed. Somethig like that:

```
<table class="table" st-table="records">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th ng-repeat="column in columns"> {{ column.title }} </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 ....
</table>
```

So my question is: how can i set attribute "st-sort" only for those columns, for which **column.sortable** is true? 
I tried to use custom directive that adds this attribute depending on **column.sortable** and it actually adds it, but st-sort not works in this case (may be because this directive compilation is happening after table compilation, i have no idea...)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
<table st-table="records">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columns" st-sort="{{(column.sortable) ? column.id : null}}">
        {{column.id}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...   
</table>
```